# Java Synchronized Cron Job and Ajax Request

Tags: java, ajax, synchronization, synchronized

I have a cron job which executes on every 5 minutes.
The cron job fetches the messages from a service and stores into database.

On JSP page an AJAX request is executing on every 1 minute.
It checks the database for new messages based on time.

Now, my problem is sometime these two processes are crossed and due to that some messages are not fetched by AJAX request.

I have make this cron job as synchronized but still it does not work.

What i need is... when cron job is running i need to hold on AJAX HTTP request.

Please guide.

Comment: Ajax Push Engine APE  or Comet may Help you.

Comment: The problem is i need to pause ajax request while cron job is running.

Answer (score 0):

You want to synchronize reading and writing in a database.
You do not want the AJAX process to read from a message table at the same time as the cron job is inserting in that table.

Your problem seems to be Phantom Reads.
This can be avoided by using database transaction and especially defining an appropriate level of transaction isolation. Phantom Reads are only prevented at isolation level TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE.

I believe your AJAX request goes to a java component which uses jdbc to look for messages in the database. If you do not have taken special care of database transactions, the default transaction isolation level in JDBC depends on your database.

Try to set your transaction isolation level to TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password);
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
```

Not all jdbc drivers support all levels of transaction isolation.

For more information look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html